# Zee General Relativity Transforming polar coordinates to Riemann normal coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

This is from Zee's book on General Relativity.  This is from Book 1, Part 1.6, on he bottom of page 89 as a "fun exercise".

Using
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\delta_{\mu\nu}+B_{\mu\nu,\lambda\sigma}x^\lambda x^\sigma+...$$
$$x^\mu=x'^\mu+M^\mu_{\nu\lambda\sigma}x'^\nu x'^\lambda x'^\sigma+...$$
I'm supposed to be able to find the curvature?  The exercise is to show that the metric $ds^2=dr^2+r^2d\theta^2$ is flat using Riemann normal coordinates $(r,\theta)\rightarrow(r_*,0)$.  The steps are as follows,

Transform the polar coordinates into locally flat coordinates.  I've taken this to mean
$$x^1=r+M^1_{111}r^3+M^1_{112}r^2\theta+M^1_{122}r\theta^2+M^1_{222}\theta^3$$
$$x^2=\theta+M^2_{111}r^3+M^1_{112}r^2\theta+M^2_{122}r\theta^2+M^2_{222}\theta^3$$
where I'm using $(x'^1,x'^2)=(r,\theta)$.

Then I think the next step is supposed to be the transformation of the metric
$$g_{rr}=1+B_{rr,11}(x^1)^2+B_{rr,12}(x^1x^2)+B_{rr,22}(x^2)^2$$
$$g_{\theta\theta}=1+B_{\theta\theta,11}(x^1)^2+B_{\theta\theta,12}(x^1x^2)+B_{\theta\theta,22}(x^2)^2$$
$$g_{r\theta}=B_{r\theta,11}(x^1)^2+B_{r\theta,12}(x^1x^2)+B_{\theta\theta}(x^2)^2$$
However, for Riemann normal coordinates, $x^2=0$, so the metric transformation should reduce to
$$g_{rr}=1+B_{rr,11}(x^1)^2$$
$$g_{\theta\theta}=1+B_{\theta\theta,11}(x^1)^2$$
$$g_{r\theta}=B_{r\theta,11}(x^1)^2$$
How is this supposed to link into Zee's definition for curvature?  He defines curvature as the determinant for the matrix which transforms the coordinates into the surface
$$z=\frac{1}{2}\vec{x}^TM\vec{x}$$
then the curvature is $\det M$.  I'm having some real trouble figuring out how to do this transformation, and I'm not sure how I've used Riemann normal coordinates is completely correct either.  Please help!

Comment: Where is this exercise in the book (page, section,ect) ?

Comment: I've added that to the start, it's bottom of p.89, Book 1, part 1.6.

Comment: You can find the answer to your question here [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/459777/75708)