# Jacobi Matrix between Cartesian and Schwarzschild coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems, computational-physics, geodesics, adm-formalism

Let $\mathcal P$ be a photon at position $\vec x =(x,y,z)$ with 3-velocity $\vec v=(v_x,v_y,v_z)$, where both are given in local Cartesian coordinates.
I want to follow the photons geodesic by numerically solving the geodesic equations, which can be written in 3+1 form as,

\begin{align}
    \frac{dx^i}{d t} &= \frac{1}{p^0}\frac{dx^i}{d\lambda} = \gamma^{ij}\frac{p_j}{p^0}-\beta^i,\\
    \frac{dp_i}{d t} &= \frac{1}{p^0}\frac{dp_i}{d\lambda}
    = -\alpha p^0\partial_i\alpha+p_k\partial_i\beta^k
      -\frac{1}{2}\partial_i\gamma^{lm}\frac{p_l p_m}{p^0},\\
    \frac{dt}{d\lambda}   &= p^0 = \frac{1}{\alpha}\sqrt{\gamma^{ij} p_i p_j}.
\end{align}

I extract the quantities $\alpha,\beta^i,\gamma^{ij}$ from the Schwarzschild metric and use a Runge-Kutta 4 algorithm to integrate the ODE's.

From my given Cartesian starting values $\vec x$ and $\vec v$ I can calculate the starting values for the differential equations $x^\bar i$ and $p_\bar i$, where the bared indices stand for Cartesian coordinates.

Question: What are the coordinate transformations and how do I determine the Jacobi matrices $\Lambda^i_{\ \ \bar i}$
and $\Lambda_i^{\ \ \bar i}$ to transform my Cartesian starting values to Schwarzschild coordinates?

\begin{align}
    \begin{array}{l}
        r=r(x,y,z) \\
        \theta = \theta(r,y,z)\\
        \phi = \phi(x,y,z)
    \end{array}
    ,\qquad
    p_i = \Lambda_i^{\ \ \bar i} p_\bar i
\end{align}

On first glance Schwarzschild coordinates look like spherical polar coordinates, but if i transform them accordingly and calculate the norm of my velocity vector with the 3-metric of the Schwarzschild spacetime, the norm is not preserved,

\begin{align}
    |\vec v| = \sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2} = 1 \neq \sqrt{\gamma_{ij}v^i v^j}
\end{align}

Comment: I don't see how you can just "change coordinates".  That only works when the spaces have the same geometry, but Cartesian coordinates are for  flat space and Schwarzschild implies curved

Comment: You can always construct a local reference frame around any observer which is locally flat.

Comment: Only to quadratic order.  The Christoffle symbols vanish to linear order. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/392521/transforming-to-riemann-normal-coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformation of a vector from local Cartesian coordinates to Schwarzschild coordinates can be done in two steps.

Step 1: Transform the Cartesian vector to spherical coordinates with the Jacobian,

\begin{align}
    v^\hat i = \Lambda^\hat i_{\ \ \bar i} v^\bar i.
\end{align}

Indices with a bar and hat correspond to Cartesian and spherical coordinates respecitvely.

Step 2: Transform the spherical coordinates to Schwarzschild coordinates. The corresponding Jacobian can be extracted from the transformation law of any tensor which we know in both systems,

\begin{align}
\gamma_{ij} = \Lambda^\hat i_{\ \ i}\Lambda^\hat j_{\ \ j} \gamma_{\hat i\hat j}.
\end{align}

Here I use the 3-metric which we know in both coordinate frames. Unadorned indices represent tensors in the Schwarzschild spacetime. In general the above equation yields a system of 9 quadratic equations which can be difficult to solve. However, In the case of spherical and Schwarzschild coordinates it simplifies to 3 quadratic equation, due to both 3-metrics being diagonal,

\begin{align}
\gamma_{11} &= \Lambda^\hat 1_{\ \ 1}\Lambda^\hat 1_{\ \ 1} \gamma_{\hat 1\hat 1},
\quad
\gamma_{22} = \Lambda^\hat 2_{\ \ 2}\Lambda^\hat 2_{\ \ 2} \gamma_{\hat 2\hat 2},
\quad
\gamma_{33} = \Lambda^\hat 3_{\ \ 3}\Lambda^\hat 3_{\ \ 3} \gamma_{\hat 3\hat 3},\\
(1-\frac{2M}{r})^{-1} &= \Lambda^\hat 1_{\ \ 1}\Lambda^\hat 1_{\ \ 1} 1,
\qquad
r^2 = \Lambda^\hat 2_{\ \ 2}\Lambda^\hat 2_{\ \ 2} r^2,
\qquad
r^2\sin^2(\theta) = \Lambda^\hat 3_{\ \ 3}\Lambda^\hat 3_{\ \ 3} r^2\sin^2(\theta).
\end{align}

Thus, we get the following Jacobian,

\begin{align}
J = \Lambda^\hat i_{\ \ i} = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
(1-\frac{2M}{r})^{-1/2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right).
\end{align}

Note that this Jacobian transforms contravariant Schwarzschild tensors to contravariant spherical tensors or covariant spherical tensors to covariant Schwarzschild tensors,

\begin{align}
v^\hat i = \Lambda^\hat i_{\ \ i} v^i\qquad
v_i = \Lambda^\hat i_{\ \ i} v_\hat i.
\end{align}

In order to transform a contravariant spherical tensor to Schwarzschild coordinates we have to use the inverse Jacobian transformation,

\begin{align}
v_\hat i = \Lambda_\hat i^{\ \ i} v_i\qquad
v^i = \Lambda_\hat i^{\ \ i} v^\hat i.
\end{align}

with $\Lambda_\hat i^{\ \ i} = (\Lambda^\hat i_{\ \ i})^{-1} = J^{-1}$.